# Handle SDL_KeyboardEvent without window focus

Tags: events, input, keyboard, sdl-2

I'm trying to get keyboard events using SDL2.0. The following sample is working for me when I have the window's focus:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0) /* Prefer only events SDL_INIT_EVENTS */
    {
        SDL_Log("Unable to initialize SDL: %s", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_Window* gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow( "SDL Tutorial", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 640, 320, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN ); /* I don't want this window! */

    /* While no quit */
    bool quit = false;

    //Event handler
    SDL_Event e;

    //While application is running
    while( !quit )
    {
        //Handle events on queue
        while( SDL_PollEvent( &e ) != 0 )
        {
            //User requests quit
            if( e.type == SDL_QUIT )
            {
                quit = true;
            }
            //User presses a key
            else if( e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN )
            {
                printf( "Key type: %d\n", e.key.keysym.sym );
                //Select surfaces based on key press
                switch( e.key.keysym.sym )
                {
                    case SDLK_UP:
                    printf( "UP!\n" );
                    break;

                    case SDLK_DOWN:
                    printf( "DOWN!\n" );
                    break;

                    case SDLK_LEFT:
                    printf( "LEFT!\n" );
                    break;

                    case SDLK_RIGHT:
                    printf( "RIGHT!\n" );
                    break;

                    default:
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

I would like to avoid use `SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO)` without create a SDL_Window using only `SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVENTS)`. Actually, my problem is that I only can receive the events if I create the windows and focus it. Is it possible to get the events globally without the focus?

My strategy is to try to use SDL library to isolate OS events behavior and focus in record/play small events provided by an user. Other suggests are welcome.

Comment: SDL don't have that functionality. You have to use OS specific ways (like assigning keyboard press hook on windows - which is global, but still virtualised) and hope antivirus software wouldn't think your program is a keylogger.